# How to get list of all apps that in the home screen using ADB

Tags: android, adb

The command `adb shell pm list packages` print a list of all the installed apps.
But I need a list of all the apps that **displayed on the home screen ("Desktop")**.
Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know and as crazy as it is, I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dump` from [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) (*which in this case will be using `adb` as backend*) as a quick and dirty approach, while your device is showing the home screen you can do

```
$ dump  | grep 'android.widget.TextView'
```

And you'll get the icons (TextViews) plus perhaps an extra component like the date

```
         android.widget.TextView com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/clock Wednesday, Feb 16
   android.widget.TextView  Messages
   android.widget.TextView  Play Store
   android.widget.TextView  Chrome
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can use this commend

```
adb shell pm list packages -3
```

it's will filter to only show third party packages

Comment: This is in the least bit helpful. The question is asking for all apps that would appear on the home screen of the device. This would include third-party apps as well as system and manufacturer installed.